# Can't Seem to get my data out of MySQL DB with NHibernate

Tags: mysql, nhibernate, model-view-controller

So I have setup a MySQL database with table with one record.  My Solution is made up of three projects (1 domain model library, test library and my Web project). In my MVC project I have implemented NHibernate with all necessary Dll's, and

In Web project root:

```
nhibernate-configuration.xsd
nhibernate-mapping.xsd
nhibernate.config and 
<classname>.hbm.xml file - with the class it is mapping
```

In my Global.asax.cs file I have my event handlers to bind the current session:
     public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
  {

```
public MvcApplication()
{
  BeginRequest += (MvcApplication_BeginRequest);
  EndRequest += (MvcApplication_EndRequest);
}

void MvcApplication_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  CurrentSessionContext.Bind(BootStrapper.SessionFactory.OpenSession());
}

void MvcApplication_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(BootStrapper.SessionFactory).Dispose();
}
```

Then I have my BootStrapper class which returns the current session:
    public static readonly ISessionFactory SessionFactory = CreateSessionFactory();

```
  private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
  {
    var cfg = new Configuration().Configure(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "nhibernate.config"));
    cfg.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionStringName, System.Environment.MachineName);
    return cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
  }

  public static ISession GetSession()
  {
    return SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
  }
```

My Controller is being handed an object by my Ninject IoC
ProductController.cs
     public class ProductsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IProductsRepository productsRepository;

```
    public ProductsController(IProductsRepository productsRepository)
    {
      this.productsRepository = productsRepository;
    }

    public ViewResult List()
    {
        return View(productsRepository.Products.ToList());
    }

}
```

NinjectControllerFactory.cs
    public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
  {
    //Supplies Object instances
    private IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new DaisyblossomsServices());

```
//MVC calls this to get the controller for each requests
protected override IController GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
{
  if (controllerType == null)
    return null;
  return (Controller)kernel.Get(controllerType);
}
```

}

Which you will sell calls my services class DaisyblossomsServices:
    public class DaisyblossomsServices : NinjectModule
  {

```
public override void Load()
{
    Bind<IProductsRepository>().To<ProductsRepository>();
}
```

}

Where you can see IProductsRepository is bound to my ProductsRepository class:

```
public class ProductsRepository : IProductsRepository
```

{
    public IQueryable Products
    {
        get { var session = BootStrapper.GetSession();

```
    return session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Product)).List<Product>().AsQueryable();

    }
}
```

}

And my ProductsController is handed an IProductsRepository object

```
 public interface IProductsRepository
```

{
    IQueryable Products { get; }
  }

As additional information My Product.hbm.xml file which maps my Product.cs class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="Daisyblossoms.Domain"
                   namespace="Daisyblossoms">
      <class name="Product"
         table="product">
    <id name="ProductID">
      <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" column="Name" />
    <property name="Price" column="Price" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And my nhibernate.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<hibernate-configuration  xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2" >
  <session-factory name="Daisyblossoms.Domain">
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver</property>
    <property name="generate_statistics">true</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">web</property>
    <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory,     NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
    <mapping assembly="Daisyblossoms.WebUI"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And my connectionsStrings part of Web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="daisyblossoms" connectionString="Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=dbName;Uid=user;Pwd=somePSWD;pooling=false;" 
 providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
```

Any thoughts what might be my issue?

Comment: Oh, and no errors.  Its obvious it isn't retrieving any records from the DB to display.

Comment: Sorry left out my ASPX page:  I just foreach (var product in Model) and display product.Name as well as Product.Price.ToString("c")

Comment: And finally, if I change the password in the connectionString, it will error and return "Access denied for that user.  So  I assume it is connecting to the DB, with the correct credentials.  Why it's not returning the record is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that hibernate.cfg.xml has output set to "Update if newer" and that your *.hbm.xml files are marked as Embedded Resources. Those are the two most common mistakes. It also sounds like you're trying to get a lot of moving parts working at the same time. You might want to simplify things to just get a console app to connect to MySQL using NHibernate. Something like this:

```
internal class Program {
    private static void Main() {
        var cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.Configure();  // Uses hibernate.cfg.xml by default.
        // cfg.Configure("nhibernate.config");  // Or use this overload if you prefer your own name.
        var sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
        using(var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        using(var tx = session.BeginTransaction()) {
            var query = session.CreateCriteria<Product>().List();
            query.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Name));
            tx.Commit();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to exit...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

This would allow you to verify that your mappings and configuration files are correct without worrying about MVC, Ninject, etc. at the same time.

Comment: Is the cfg.xml the same thing as .config file?  I have seen both referenced, but never in the same project?

Comment: If you name your config file hibernate.cfg.xml, NHibernate loads it automatically when you call cfg.Configure() without any arguments. If you want to name your config file anything else, you need to specify the filename. So yes, they're the same thing.